# Unity sprite disappears when the camera approaches

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

when the camera approaches a part of the object and does not capture its center - the object view disappears.

**Сamera when approaching when the center of the object is captured:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvvWJ.png)

**Сamera when approaching when the center of the object is NOT captured:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t5aW.png)

The **object** is a large treant, the **center** is indicated by a transparent circle.
I use the 2D animation package to animate my treant, maybe this could be a problem

**The main question is**:
How to make part of the object visible?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be **zooming the camera in** .
Most likely reason, therefore, is that the treant gets outside of camera frustum - it gets closer to the camera than is its NearClippingPlane.

Decrease the camera's Near Clipping Plane value.

Comment: The validity and usefulness of this answer must be elevated.  10/10